# Date Interval Match Join Between 2 tables in DBT - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt, dateinterval

I am trying to implement date interval check while joining 2 tables in **DBT using Bigquery**.

Table 1 (Customer) has 3 columns. Customer ID , Product ID & Order Date.
Table 2 (Products) has 4 columns. Product ID , Start Date , End Date & Price. Same product can have different price based on Start Date & end date.

I am trying to join these 2 table based on Product ID and fetch the price where Order Date is falling between Start Date & End Date.

**Table Data & Expected Output**

**Customer**
|Customer ID|Product ID|Order Date|
|-----------|----------|----------|
|1|A|2023-07-05|
|2|A|2022-04-04|

**Products**
|Product ID|Start Date|End Date|Price|
|----------|----------|--------|-----|
|A|2020-01-01|2021-12-31|100|
|A|2022-01-01|2022-05-05|120|
|A|2022-05-06|9999-12-31|130|

**Output**
|Customer ID|Product ID|Order Date|Price|
|-----------|----------|----------|-----|
|1|A|2023-07-05|130|
|2|A|2022-04-04|120|

To implement this , I have joined the 2 tables in DBT based on Product ID and then applied filter condition to select the record where Order Date is falling between Start Date & End Date. It is working fine and providing desired output.

Another approach is to divide the product table into active & in-active records and first join with active and then further join with inactive records with date interval check to find any match.

Is there any other better approach ? Some out of the box solution which DBT provides ? Customer table will have 1M records & Product will have around .8M records.

Comment: Use text to share details rather than images, and please share which database are you using

Comment: Hi . I am using Bigquery for the database. Tried to add text , but somehow the formatting is not working to showcase as a table format.

Comment: I would just write it in the join. on a.product_id = b.product id and a.order_date between b.start_date and b.end_date (or with >= and < if you don't want to include start/end date)